# Simple left right scrolling marquee

Tags: javascript, scroll, marquee

What is the lightest left-right scrolling marquee around?

I would prefer if it 'bounced'... by that I mean rather than going around in a loop it would be better that it scrolled left until it was all shown and then scrolled right.

I know its kinda retro... I am thinking of using it instead of truncating text.

Thanks.

Comment: wouldn't a `<marquee>` do the job? looks like w3 is determined on reviving it - http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-marquee/

Comment: That's the end game with Silky Smooth Marquee. The default marquee element has very poor animation (skippy, laggy, etc), but the Silky Smooth Marquee (and some others like it) reuse the existing marquee tag and replace the elements in order to make something that animates less crappily; meanwhile leaving the original marquee markup intact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the [Silky Smooth Marquee](http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/).

It uses the standard html marquee tag, so it will work without javascript enabled.  However, with javascript enabled, it uses jquery to enhance the marquee and provides many customization options.

Here's the [demo page](http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html).

Comment: enjoy!  but remember, geocities has died... :P

Comment: and `<marquee>` and `<blink>` are hugely responsible :P

Comment: Does anybody really find this to be "smooth"? It flickers horribly like a bad flourecent light on my machine... It's not as bad as the native, which jerks across the screen as a sick ant, but still...

Comment: What's the reccomended system requirements for "smooth scrolling"? Dual core intel 2GHz with 2GB ram is apparently not enough...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this quite simple with jquery and some css:

```
// HTML 
<div id="myWrapperID" style="width: 300px;">
<div id="myElementID" style="float:left">[Lorem ipsum]</div>
</div>


// JS
(function (){
var ml,
    elem = $('#myElementID'),
    maxMarginLeft = $('#myWrapperID').width() - elem.width(),
    doMarquee = function () {
        ml = parseInt(elem.css('marginLeft'), 10) === 0 ? maxMarginLeft : 0;
        elem.animate({ marginLeft: ml + 'px' }, doMarquee);
    }

elem.css('marginLeft', '0px');
    doMarquee();    
}());
```